How to repair a chip in a window?
There is a small (less than 1/4 inch) round chip in the outer pane of a tilt-in window.  I would like to repair it before winter so that freeze/thaw cycles don't cause it to crack.  I see many windshield repair kits, but none for windows.  Would they work OK?

They should.  Windshield glass is tempered and has a plastic film in the middle of it(I think), but it is glass.  A glass/window repair shop would have better info.  A fast search says it is possible.  Be sure to read all instructions, especially about cleaning.

how big is your window that it's not cheaper to just replace the damaged pane?
